# How to update row in Android?

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to update particular column on next button.But after run the application insert one value doubly.How can i update if that value is already in the table.Thanks to appreciate.

Here is my DataBase code.

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
    SQLiteDatabase sqlDatabase;

        //Database name
       public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Test.db";

       //Database Version
       static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

       public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
             this.sqlDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();  
        }


       public static final String QUESTION_ANSWERS_TABLE = "question_answers";

        //Table REGISTRATION_TABLE columns Name
       public static final String  Question_Id = "question_id";
       public static final String Question_No = "question_no";
       public static final String Question_Type = "question_type";
       public static final String Question = "question";
       public static final String Answer = "answer";
       public static final String Options_ID = "option";
       public static final String Marks = "mark";

    @Override
       public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
       {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         String  CREATE_QUESTION_ANSWERS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "+ QUESTION_ANSWERS_TABLE + "("
                  + Question_Id + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " 
                  + Question_No + " TEXT,"
                  + Question_Type + " TEXT, "
                  + Question+ " TEXT, "
                  + Answer + " TEXT, "
                  + Marks + " TEXT, "
                  + Options_ID + " TEXT "+");";
          db.execSQL(CREATE_QUESTION_ANSWERS_TABLE);

      }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + QUESTION_ANSWERS_TABLE);
         onCreate(db);
    }



    public boolean insertQueDetails(String strQuestionNo , String strQuestionType, String strQuestion, String strAnswer, 
                                    String strMark   , String strOptionId )
       {
          SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
          ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
          contentValues.put(Question_No, strQuestionNo);
          contentValues.put(Question_Type, strQuestionType);
          contentValues.put(Question, strQuestion);
          contentValues.put(Answer, strAnswer);
          contentValues.put(Marks, strMark);    
          contentValues.put(Options_ID, strOptionId);

          db.insert(QUESTION_ANSWERS_TABLE, null, contentValues);
          db.close();
          return true;
       }


    public void updateAnswerRow(Integer strQ_Id , String strAnswer)
    {
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
            args.put(Answer, strAnswer);

            db.update("question_answers", args, "question_id = ? ", new String[] { Integer.toString(strQ_Id) } );
     }


}
```

Here is my Activity code.

```
  public void checkEmptyTable()
    {
        DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this.getApplicationContext());
        sqdb = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        Cursor cur = sqdb.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT(question_id) AS Count_Id FROM question_answers", null);
        if (cur != null) 
        {
            cur.moveToFirst();  
            // Always one row returned.
               int Count_Id = cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex("Count_Id"));        
               System.out.println("Count_Id in Table is Empty !!!! i = " + Count_Id);  // Zero count means empty table.

        }cur.close();
    }

    public void storingResult()
    {
            AnswerOptions = (RadioButton) findViewById(Options_RadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
            String str_AnswerOptions = AnswerOptions.getText().toString().trim();
            System.out.println("rbVal = " + str_AnswerOptions);
            if (str_AnswerOptions.equals(((Datastructure) Vectore_mquestionDatabaseStructure .get(StaticClass.QuestionNumber)).Answer))
                {
                    if (!StaticClass.isTest)
                    {
                        String str_queNo = button_QuestionLimit.getText().toString().trim();
                        String strstrqueType = txtViewQuestiontype.getText().toString().trim();
                        String str_que = txtViewQuestion.getText().toString().trim();
                        String str_marks = "1";

                        if(Count_Id == 0 )
                        {
                            databaseHelper.insertQueDetails(str_queNo, strstrqueType, str_que, str_AnswerOptions, str_marks  , strOption_Id);
                            System.out.println("str_queNo = " + str_queNo + ", strstrqueType = " + strstrqueType +" , str_que = " + str_que + " , str_AnswerOptions = " + str_AnswerOptions + ", str_marks = " + str_marks + ", strOption_Id = " + strOption_Id);
                            Toast.makeText(this, " Right Answer ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        else if(Count_Id == convertVector)
                        {
                             databaseHelper.updateAnswerRow(convertVector , str_AnswerOptions);
                             Toast.makeText(this, "Updated SuccesFully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                             System.out.println("Answer Updated Successfully !!!");
                        }
                    }

                }

                else
                {
                    if (!StaticClass.isTest)

                    {
                        String str_queNo = button_QuestionLimit.getText()
                                .toString().trim();
                        String strstrqueType = txtViewQuestiontype.getText()
                                .toString().trim();
                        String str_que = txtViewQuestion.getText().toString()
                                .trim();
                        String str_marks = "0";

                        if(Count_Id == 0 )
                        {
                            databaseHelper.insertQueDetails(str_queNo, strstrqueType, str_que, str_AnswerOptions, str_marks  , strOption_Id);
                            System.out.println("str_queNo = " + str_queNo + ", strstrqueType = " + strstrqueType +" , str_que = " + str_que + " , str_AnswerOptions = " + str_AnswerOptions + ", str_marks = " + str_marks + ", strOption_Id = " + strOption_Id);
                            Toast.makeText(this, " Wrong Answer ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        else if(Count_Id == convertVector)
                        {
                             databaseHelper.updateAnswerRow(convertVector , strtext);
                             Toast.makeText(this, "Wrong Updated SuccesFully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                             System.out.println("Wrong Answer Updated Successfully !!!");
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (StaticClass.isTest)
            {
                StaticClass.resultOfTest = 1 + StaticClass.resultOfTest;
                ((Datastructure) Vectore_mquestionDatabaseStructure.elementAt(StaticClass.QuestionNumber)).setResult_Of_Test(true);
                return;
            }
    }
```

Here is My Activity Screen Shot

[image]
Here is Screen Shot[image]

Comment: What is updateAnswerRow method? Post its body.

Comment: Post your Database Code.

Comment: updateAnswerRow method in database is right it will update your row or we can say it will change value of Answer.

Comment: What is problem? I dont see any problem in code.

Comment: @DhavalGondaliya :I have implement if id == 0 then i want to insert the row but id is already there then updated the value .But value is updated and insert repeatedly.Means insert value and update value both are insert saperately.

Comment: @DhavalGondaliya : - So then Why not update.If first i have insert row in id 1 then update , but it creates again 1 id table not rplace with the same id it creates two rows with same id.

Comment: Need to check whole code for that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63084/discussion-between-dhaval-gondaliya-and-sheetal-kahane).

Comment: @SheetalKahane Did you get solution?

Comment: @Dhaval Gondaliya:- Not yet , Actually i have used xmlparsar for objective question and answer test.And i have lots of issue with that .Row is update but but not same id it will create again second id means with the same question and same question no.

Answer (score 0):

Make Getter and setter class of all the data you want to save into database and use that for saving and updating data.

Change your Update Method in Database:

```
public void updateAnswerRow(gettersetterclass classs)
    {
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
            contentValues.put(Question_No, classs.getuestionno);
            contentValues.put(Question_Type, classs.getquestiontype);
            contentValues.put(Question, classs.getquestion);
            contentValues.put(Answer, classs.getAnswer);
            contentValues.put(Marks, classs.getmarks);    
            contentValues.put(Options_ID, classs.getoptionid);
            db.update(QUESTION_ANSWERS_TABLE , args, Question_Id +" = ? ", new String[] { Integer.toString(classs.getstrQ_Id) } );
     }
```

If you have made gettersetter class already then use it.